# quicklist arrangement and tweaks

Tags: unity, development

I'm setting up my site to use Unity's web-app integration api, but I would like more control over how the quick list is displayed. I would like to arrange the items in the same order the site shows them but the quick list seems to want to put them in alphabetical order. It would also be nice if I could add a spacer or some sort of visual break between one section of the list and another. this is what I have so far: http://www.thescribecommons.org

The question, are these available via the API? Where can I find a formatting commands list?